# Swift: Error when creating a Wrapper Class for a Generic Class conforming Generic Protocol

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols, type-erasure

I want to create a Wrapper class for a generic class that is conforming a generic protocol, but for some reason I cannot make it work properly.

The idea behind is to use the wrapper **AnyNetworkRequest** as an Erased-Type along the application, so that there is no need to define the Generic types as in **_NetworkRequest**.

I cannot see what is missing/wrong on **AnyNetworkRequest**. If any could point me out what is missing or wrong I'd appreciate it.

```swift
// Protocol with associatedtypes

public protocol NetworkRequest {

    associatedtype RequestSerializationType: RequestSerializationProtocol
    associatedtype RequestResponseType: NetworkResponseProtocol

    var requestSerializer: RequestSerializationType { get }
    var requestResponse: RequestResponseType? { get }
}


// Generic Request

public class _NetworkRequest<RequestSerializationType: RequestSerializationProtocol, RequestResponseType: NetworkResponseProtocol>: NetworkRequest {

    fileprivate init() {}

    public lazy var requestSerializer: RequestSerializationType = { RequestSerializationType.init() }()
    public var requestResponse: RequestResponseType?
}

// Concrete Request

public class DataNetworkRequest: _NetworkRequest<ConcreteHTTPRequestSerializer, ConcreteDataNetworkResponse> {}

// Concrete Request

public class JSONDataNetworkRequest: _NetworkRequest<ConcreteJSONRequestSerializer, ConcreteJSONDataNetworkResponse> {}


// Type Erased Wrapper
// Cannot make this wrapper work
// Error 1: Type 'AnyNetworkRequest' does not conform to protocol 'NetworkRequest'
// Error 2: Reference to invalid associated type 'RequestSerializationType' of type 'AnyNetworkRequest'

public class AnyNetworkRequest : NetworkRequest { //E1

    private let request : _NetworkRequest<RequestSerializationType, RequestResponseType> //E2

    init<T: NetworkRequest>(_ networkRequest: T) where T.RequestSerializationType == RequestSerializationType, T.RequestResponseType == RequestResponseType {
        request = networkRequest
    }
}
```

EDITED: 1st MODIFICATION

```swift
// Protocol with associatedtypes

public protocol NetworkRequest {

    associatedtype RequestSerializationType: RequestSerializationProtocol
    associatedtype RequestResponseType: NetworkResponseProtocol

    var requestSerializer: RequestSerializationType { get }
    var requestResponse: RequestResponseType? { get }
}


// Generic Request

public class _NetworkRequest<RST: RequestSerializationProtocol, RRT: NetworkResponseProtocol>: NetworkRequest {

    public typealias RequestSerializationType = RST
    public typealias RequestResponseType = RRT


    fileprivate init() {}

    public lazy var requestSerializer: RequestSerializationType = { RequestSerializationType.init() }()
    public var requestResponse: RequestResponseType?
}

// Concrete Request

public class DataNetworkRequest: _NetworkRequest<ConcreteHTTPRequestSerializer, ConcreteDataNetworkResponse> {}

// Concrete Request

public class JSONDataNetworkRequest: _NetworkRequest<ConcreteJSONRequestSerializer, ConcreteJSONDataNetworkResponse> {}


// Type Erased Wrapper
// Cannot make this wrapper work
// Error 1: Type 'AnyNetworkRequest' does not conform to protocol 'NetworkRequest'
// Error 2: Reference to invalid associated type 'RequestSerializationType' of type 'AnyNetworkRequest'

public class AnyNetworkRequest : NetworkRequest { //E1

    /*  // E1 forces me to include typealiases
        public typealias RequestSerializationType = <#type#>
        public typealias RequestResponseType = <#type#>
    */

    private let request : _NetworkRequest<RequestSerializationType, RequestResponseType>

    var requestSerializer: RequestSerializationType { //E2
        return request.requestSerializer
    }

    var requestResponse: RequestResponseType? {
        return request.requestResponse
    }

    init<T: NetworkRequest>(_ networkRequest: T) where T.RST == RequestSerializationType, T.RRT == RequestResponseType {
        request = networkRequest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Errors are quite straightforward to explain.

1) Your `AnyNetworkRequest` class really does not conform to `NetworkRequest` protocol. And I don't see why it should, by the way. Unsatisfied requirements are `requestSerializer` and `requestResponse` properties along with needed type aliases. In general, you may rewrite this as following:

```
public class AnyNetworkRequest: NetworkRequest {

    var requestSerializer: RequestSerializationType { 
       return request.requestSerializer
    }

    var requestResponse: RequestResponseType? { 
       return request.requestResponse
    }

    private let request : _NetworkRequest<RequestSerializationType, RequestResponseType>

   // ...
}
```

BUT it takes us to

2) Where you need to specify something for associated types. You cannot use `RequestSerializationType` and `RequestResponseType` in generic declaration as they are not concrete types.

So you cannot perform type erasure in such manner.

I don't know why you need to get rid of generics here aside of typing less letters, but what I can offer is to use type aliases like:

```
typealias DataNetworkRequest = _NetworkRequest<ConcreteHTTPRequestSerializer, ConcreteDataNetworkResponse>

typealias JSONDataNetworkRequest = _NetworkRequest<ConcreteJSONRequestSerializer, ConcreteJSONDataNetworkResponse>
```

This way you will elude redundant inheritance and have more clearly expressed types in case it's your goal.

`AnyNetworkRequest` will not be needed at all in this case.

Comment: Thanks @Bohdan Ivanov, I'll use your points to be more precise:
1) AnyNetworkRequest is still failing because it does not declare the typealiases of NetworkRequest protocol. What I want is to assign values to them based on the networkRequest attribute you can see in the initializer. I thought the 'where' conditions in the init would be enough for it.
2)Concrete Requests (Data or JSON) have their own implementations (not included here) so typealias is not an option. I want to work with common erased-types for my API's as GET(_ r: AnyNetworkRequest) or POST(_ r: AnyNetworkRequest)

Comment: No, "where" condition is not enough, because AnyNetworkRequest is not generic w/o type aliases. 

Have you tried to solve this problem without using generics? It may help as well. For example, you can use protocol-oriented approach. Beware: it will barely works with associatedtype and stuff like this

Comment: You may want also to make generic not whole class but rather some methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is not actually how type erasers work - the role of type erasers is to allow homogenous interfaces in a heterogenous world, where many types can conform to the protocols interested into.

Take for example `AnySequence`, it's interface is similarly to this:

```swift
struct AnySequence<Element>: Sequence {
    init<S>(_ sequence: S) where S == Sequence, S.Element == Element
}
```

`AnySequence` erases the original sequence type, not the `Element` type. In your case you cannot get rid of the two associated types, a type eraser can only hide the actual class that conforms to `NetworkRequest`. `AnyRequest` would still need information about the two types.